# How to prefer ipv6 over ipv4 only for specific websites?

Tags: windows-7, networking, firefox, google-chrome, ipv6

I only have ipv6 connectivity via a HE tunnel on my router, so normally I want to prefer ipv4 over ipv6. For some websites however, I would like to prefer ipv6.

Right now I have just set DisabledComponents to 0x20 and hard coded the ipv6 resolution into my hosts file for the sites i want to access over ipv6. Since these ip addresses change at times, this is not a good solution.

Any ideas on how to handle this in a non-clunky way? Some kind of Chrome/Firefox add-on might do the trick, but I couldn't find one for this purpose.

Comment: A different question on askubuntu site (http://askubuntu.com/questions/9181/how-to-let-the-browser-prefer-ipv6-over-ipv4) gives a hint that it is OS that sets what's preffered in this case.

Answer (score -1):

Use the IPv6 address of the website. For example, to go to http://www.google.com , use this address `http://[2001:4860:0:2001::68]/`

Comment: Nobody wants to manually type in an IPv6 address every time they visit a website. Besides it wouldn't even work, because the browser would no longer send the domain name in the `Host` header, so you could end up on a completely different site.